# Select cell adress from Excel using OLEDB in C#

Tags: c#, excel, select, oledb

I have a following connection string:

```
string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=template.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;""";
```

Connection is successful. And i have following data in excel sheet

```
ID  Channel Upload
2_b_20_1    1   0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_2    2   0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_3    3   0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_4    4   0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_5    5   0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_6    6   0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_7    7   0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_8    8   0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_9    9   0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_10   10  0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_11   11  0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_12   12  0,0 Mbps
2_b_20_13   13  0,0 Mbps
```

I need to find address of cell containing string in the first column.
So in pseudo select it would be like:

```
Select "CellAdress" from [MySheet] where Value like '2_b_20_1'
```

and it should return address of this cell.

I dont have any code yet about it, i just dont know where to start from.

Is it possible at all? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the connection string I always go to [ConnectionString.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com).
Search for the type of Excel file version your trying to open.

I'm guessing for you it should be:

```cs
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=template.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"";
```

Has for the SQL query string, for excel you should do it like this

```cs
    "SELECT * FROM [<SheetName>$<optional range>]";
```

For exemple if the worksheet name is MySheet you can do

```cs
    "SELECT * FROM [MySheet$]";
```

If you want to select a specific range you can do it like this.

```cs
    "SELECT * FROM [MySheet$A1:C200]";
```

In your case (without knowing the rest of your code is hard) but I believe what you need is:

```cs
    "SELECT * FROM [MySheet$] WHERE ID='2_b_20_1'";
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM [MySheet$] WHERE ID='2_b_20_1'";
This one works perfectly. Thank you!
I didnt have headers on xls, I added them and works great