# Import Excel Sheet to DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I'm using Visual studio 2010. Using OleDB, How to import Selected Columns and Rows of Excel sheet to my `datagridView1`? Let's assume that my Rows and Columns starts at B13 and get atleast 20 rows of my B13.

Does anyone have a example code or a link that can help me to do this? Thank You So Much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by this command:

```
"SELECT * FROM [<SheetName>$<optional range>]";
//Ex : OleDbCommand OleConnection = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B13:B33]", Con);
```

Source : [Select cell adress from Excel using OLEDB in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634718/select-cell-adress-from-excel-using-oledb-in-c-sharp)

Full code here:

```
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg_im = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg_im.Filter = "Excel File|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
            //dlg_im.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx";

            if (dlg_im.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = dlg_im.FileName;

                string name = "Sheet1";
                string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

                OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                OleDbCommand OleConnection = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B13:B33]", Con);
                Con.Open();

                OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(OleConnection);
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(data);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 320;
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }


        MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

Comment: It Works! Thankyou so much!!

Comment: Sir how about 2 Columns?

Comment: @Michael :  "SELECT * FROM [MySheet$A15:B20]";

Comment: how to import it to my own column? Like i have column "NAMES"

Comment: Could you please describe more detail ? As I understand, you have a datagridview table with column "NAMES". Then you want to read excel file and import one of the columns in excel file to column "NAMES" in datagridview . Am I right ?

Comment: @ Nguyen Thanh Binh Yup you are right! Because i already have data's like some information in my datagridView. For example i import a column in excel file and load it to my column names in datagridView because it creates a new row..

Comment: @Michael I  have 2 questions: Is your Column in datagridview empty or not ? And You want import a column in excel file and overwrite to your comlum in datagridview or You want to add a new row in datagridview and import for each row in excel file.

Comment: @ Nguyen Thanh Binh My column is Empty i just want to import and overwrite it to my column. For example i have Column ID, Name and Grade. Column Grade is empty i just want to import grade from excel to my column grade. Thankyou sir!

Answer (score 1):

In case of you want to import a column of excel file to an empty column in the available datagridview.

Ex: You have a datagridview as below, and you want to read excel file and import to column "Class"

[image]

[image]

Let's assume you want to add data from range A1 to A11 of excel file to column "Class" (2nd column) in datagridview

```
            private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog dlg_im = new OpenFileDialog();
                dlg_im.Filter = "Excel File|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
                //dlg_im.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx";

                if (dlg_im.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = dlg_im.FileName;

                    string name = "Sheet1";
                    string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

                    OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                    OleDbCommand OleConnection = new OleDbCommand("SELECT *FROM [Sheet1$A1:A11]", Con);
                    Con.Open();

                    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(OleConnection);
                    DataTable data = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(data);


                    int i = 0;//The position of row in datagridview you want to start adding
                    foreach (DataRow dr in data.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dr.ItemArray[0]);
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dr.ItemArray[0];//Cells[2] --> Columns[2] --> Column Class
                        i++;
                    }

                    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

This is OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much sir! Big help!!

Comment: sir got a small problem, what if the column class in excel has a empty rows? I want import A1-A10 but my class column in excel has only a1-a5 isn't that possible that i can get also empty columns without getting Out of range Excetion? Because i got an error. I try to put only 1 data in column of Class in excel just to put A1 and still get the A1-A10 in query of string constr.

Comment: Or only iif have 2 rows in datagridView and 5 rows in excel how import just only 2? so if i add 1 more row and i import it will import 3 rows in excel. isn't that possible?

Comment: i always got System.Argument.OutOfRangeException:Index was out of range
because in my Excel File i import 20 rows with empty rows to my datagridView lets say Example. in my excel file A1-10 I only have 5data but i will import 20rows when i import it and i have only 5 rows as well in my datagridView, But my range is A1-A10. If my datagridView has only 5rows it will import the all the A1-A10, Just like your First Code sir, my problem in that it is creating a new row it didnt match to my rows in dataGridView Thankyou so much sir!

Comment: @Michael . You can check my comments below

Answer (score 0):

"what if the column class in excel has a empty rows? I want import A1-A10 but my class column in excel has only a1-a5 isn't that possible that i can get also empty columns without getting Out of range Excetion? Because i got an error. I try to put only 1 data in column of Class in excel just to put A1 and still get the A1-A10 in query of string constr."

--> As you see in the picture below I tried putting only 1 data "A1" in class column in excel file. When I import this excel file to datagridview, I don't face any Out of range Excetion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Or only iif have 2 rows in datagridView and 5 rows in excel how import just only 2? so if i add 1 more row and i import it will import 3 rows in excel. isn't that possible? "

--> Yes, This is possible.
Firstly, you need to determine how many rows you need to add to datagridview.

Ex: Your datagridview has 2 rows, but your excel file has 5 rows

--> You need to add 3 rows to datagridview before importing.

Add code lines in hightlight area to your code.

[image]

Don't forget to define "data" as global instead of local.

[image]